# Installing MongoDB- mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork returns: bash: mongod: command not found

Tags: mongodb, installation, terminal, fork, config

Downloading MongoDB
I'm finding it hard to download MongoDB in the background. I'm successful with the command:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.2 ,
```

but every time i try the command:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork,
```

it writes:

```
bash: mongod: command not found.
```

The command:

```
brew services list
```

works and runs the following:

```
Name Status User File

mongodb-community@4.2 started myName ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2.plist
```

However, when I run:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork
```

It writes:

```
bash: mongod: command not found
```

Any help?

I am quite new to Computer Science and I only got recently acquainted with the Terminal so be nice!

Answer (score 0):

`mongod` is not found, `/usr/bin/mongod` - or wherever it is installed - should work.

Typically when you install a service, then you don't need to start it.

`brew services start mongodb-community@4.2` should be automatically executed when you boot the computer, I think this it at least the default behaviour.

When it runs then you cannot execute `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` - you cannot start mongod multiple times (unless you use a different config file with different `storage.dbPath` and `net.port`)

In principle `brew services start mongodb-community@4.2` and `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` are the same. With `mongod ...` you just get a terminal window staying open, while `brew services start` runs in background.